# Calling gcc to compile multiple files with Python

Tags: python, c, gcc

I'm trying to build a simple IDE that is web based in Python. For now, this IDE will support C only. I know it is possible to call the gcc with Python to compile and run a single C file. But what if I would like to compile and run multiple C files from a single project (i.e. linking .h files and .c files), is this possible? If yes, can you please tell me how?

Comment: I think using subprocesses you can do whatever you like, but note that you also need makefile for linking object files

Comment: @luminousmen You don't need a makefile to link any more than you need it to compile c files.  With that said, a makefile would seem to be the way to go the OP's needs.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons what do you mean by "OP" in "OP's needs"?

Comment: @JudeMaranga You.  "Original Poster".

Comment: @JudeMaranga, he asked about compiling multiple C files. How do you think it's possible to achieve this without writing Makefile? You don't know the logic and needs of the program (for example libraries, using specific language standard etc)

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming you want to handle all type of projects and their dependencies (which is not easy) the best way is to have a module that generates a `Makefile` for the project and use it to compile and solve all dependencies

Comment: How do I use the Makefile like how do I compile it?

Comment: There are many tutorials out there that are easy to follow.
You could look for `cmake` or `autotools`.
Basically you create a Makefile that corresponds to your project: which files/directories need to be compiled/included what depends on what etc...
finally you call `make` which will read that file and build you whatever you asked it to build (an executable, static/shared lib or both etc...)